# boost promise/future compilation issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, future

I am trying to run the following code which is a cut and paste from example given in boost pages (VS2012)

[boost source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.at_thread_exit)

```
void thread_func(boost::promise<int>&& p)
{
    //p.set_value_at_thread_exit(find_the_answer());
}

int main()
{
    boost::promise<int> p;
    boost::thread t(thread_func,boost::move(p)) ;
    t.detach(); // we're going to wait on the future 
    std::cout<<p.get_future().get()<<std::endl;
 }
```

And I receive the follosing error message

> c:\utils\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp(389):
>   error C2248: 'boost::promise::promise' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class 'boost::promise'

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any version of MSVC and thus can't check my answer against reality, but here's my hypothesis anyway:

```
'boost::promise::promise' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::promise'
```

This indicates that someone is trying to access a private member of `boost::promise`. We can conclude that that "someone" isn't `boost::promise` itself, because `boost::promise` definitely has access to its own private members! This means that the identifier at the beginning of the line, `boost::promise::promise`, must be the name of the private member in question (not the name of the would-be accessor).

`boost::promise::promise` is the name of *some constructor* of `boost::promise`. Unfortunately MSVC isn't telling us *which* constructor it is.

```
boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp(389):
```

This indicates that the offending member-access is somewhere in one of `boost::thread`'s members. And it must be somewhere that the `thread` is dealing with objects of type `boost::promise`. That means that almost certainly, the culprit is somewhere on this line of your code:

```
boost::thread t(thread_func, boost::move(p));
```

What could be going wrong?

---

Well, my hypothesis is based on the fact that "making a constructor private" is a pre-C++11 idiom meaning "hey, don't use this constructor". (In C++11 we say `=delete` instead.) And `boost::promise` is a move-only type — it would be reasonable for it to `=delete` its copy constructor, or in C++03 declare its copy constructor `private`. (Heck, it might declare the `=delete`'d constructor `private` in C++11, too. Why not, right?)

So *assuming* that the copy constructor is to blame, the next question is why `boost::thread` is trying to access the copy constructor. My hypothesis here is that `boost::move(p)` does not do what you think it does: somehow it is returning a plain old lvalue reference, which `boost::thread` therefore attempts to copy using the `private` copy constructor. This is probably due to compiling in some weird half-C++11 mode — see below.

The fix is probably to compile in strict C++03 mode, or to get a compiler with better C++11 conformance so that you can ditch all these Boost hacks. (You probably shouldn't be attempting to use `boost::thread` and `boost::future` in C++11, because C++11 already has `std::thread` and `std::future` built into the language.)

---

I'm not 100% sure (because it seems unbelievable) but I think you might get into this situation with *any* `BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE` class, if you're compiling with `BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS` but without `BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES`. At least that's how it looks from reading the code in Boost 1.55.